# How to change shadow transparency for Diagram.net shapes?

Tags: draw, shadow, diagram, draw.io

In diagram.net editor, I want to keep a background shadow for shapes as non transparent (i.e. full black/ bold color) but the default shadow is always in transparent mode. Is there any way to do so in diagram.net (previously known as draw.io) tool?

Left shadow is the default and right shadow is what I am expecting.

[image: Current]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible. https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1671